# Add and update a list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field. When the user start typing I'm using the "click" function to do some logic with the text.

The thing I would like to do is to have a list that gets updated when the user have entered more than 3 characters.

As soon as the users enters more characters the "Dona" part below gets updated.

The user enteres "Dona.."

The list says:

Add "Dona" as a contact
Add a task with the Subject "Dona"
and so on

What I have today is:

```
$("#inp").keyup(function() {
if ($("#inp").text.length > 3) {
 $("#list").append('<li></li>')
}
});
```

I cant get the counter to work. I'm able to append

but dont know how to pick it again later for updating

Comment: So what's your specific question? What have you tried? Can you show us some code? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` is a method, `text()`. But since you're dealing with a field, you should be using `val()` instead.

Change your code to

```
$("#inp").on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 3) { //<-- text(), not text
        $("#list").append('<li>'+$(this).val()+'</li>')
    }
});
```

Also, note I use `$(this)` (no need to make jQuery look up the element again) and have switched to using `on()` to bind the event.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tbdYH/)

Comment: This code does only return 0.  $("#inp").on('keyup', function () {
        alert($(this).text().length);

Comment: I mean. When I test this code by just using an alert with the value of text().length it only return 0, regardless of the real characters in the input box.

Comment: D'oh - I should pay more attention. It's an input, so should obviously be `val()`, not `text()`. Think I was pretty sleepy :) Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code you suggested. My code looks like this now

Nothing happens when I enter more than 3 characters.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:53230/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js">          </script>
<h1>test</h1>
<input id="inp" type="text" class="t" />

<ul id="list">
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#inp").click(function () {
    //SOME OTHER NOT RELEVANT CODE
});

$("#inp").on('keyup', function () {
        if ($(this).text().length > 3) { 
            $("#list").append('<li></li>')
        }
    });
   </script>
```